# Query in AWS Athena with dynamic date

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm executing this query:

SELECT tvd_data_hora FROM "mydb"."i_public_0622" limit 10;

but I need to get dynamicaly current MMYY to query, like:

SELECT tvd_data_hora FROM "mydb"."i_public_**0822**" limit 10;

Comment: Have you tried prepared statements https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html ?

Comment: I don't know it's works, because a need that my table name be dynamic. Like, SELECT tvd_data_hora FROM "mydb"."i_public_[**current_month_and_year**]" limit 10;